# AngularJS dropdown selected values need as JSON

Tags: angularjs, json, forms, dropdown

I have multiple dropdowns in my application which are populating through a json (which is a map basically) given in controller.

For first dropdown if I select `xyz` value, then corresponding `xyz1` values should come in dropdown and similarly for third dropdown. This all is happening fine currently. But now I want these user selected values to get in json form so that I can send back to backend for further processing. I am not getting selected values but the wrong second dropdown values if I print on console.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/pallavi1811/pen/dGPBEd) and

[working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gLAPD2pO4vfQqpxFIGp8?p=preview)

Comment: Please format your question properly and check your codepen, because currently it isn't working (no AngularJS included).

Comment: Seems it is working here.. http://plnkr.co/edit/gLAPD2pO4vfQqpxFIGp8?p=preview. If you mean something else, pls mention. Do you mean the order is mixed up?

Comment: thanks. on submit i want to print the selected dropdown values but it is printing wrong values. can you suggest how do i get selected form values?

Comment: @PitchaiPazhani - have added submitform function after json. can you check where i am going wrong here.

Comment: what is your expected output if select ApHelpDesk, CreateNewIncidentApHelpDeskPage, ReOpenIncident successively?

Comment: @Pitchai - if i select ITSM->ITSMIncidentPage->searchFilterInConfigItemLookUp and enter randome values in input box (like- "abc", "xyz", true). i should be able to get all these above entered values in JSON form and print them on console.

Answer (score 0):

Your codepen seems to be confusing and not working. As you already have the implemention for dropdown I will continue from here about how to get the data from the drop down and convert the data into a JSON.

After getting the data from the dropdown create a JSON object and store it.
I have written a small example to show how to store the data.

```
 $scope.selectedState = function(item) {
      var output = {};
      output.name = item.name;
      $scope.viewOutput = output;
    };
```

**Update:**

I tried hard but could not get the values using angular way. If you are still looking for an answer then we can use basic javascript way. Refer plunker for the same.

```
$scope.submitMyForm = function() {
      /* while compiling form , angular created this object*/
      var pgObj = $scope.pageObj;
      var pgClass = $scope.pageClass;
      var pgMethod = $scope.pageObjMethod;

      var pgObjvalue = document.getElementById('pageObj').value;
      var pgClassvalue = document.getElementById('pageClass').value;
      var pgMethodvalue = document.getElementById('pageMethod').value;

      $scope.output = {'object' : pgObjvalue, 'class': pgClassvalue, 'method': pgMethodvalue};
      console.log(data);
    };
```

Working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xdi8gB?p=preview).

P.S: If you figured out the answer using angular way then do let me know after posting it in the answer section.

Comment: @Che- this is working plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/gLAPD2pO4vfQqpxFIGp8?p=preview

Comment: @user1814044 What is the output that you are looking for?

Comment: @Che- if i select ITSM->ITSMIncidentPage->searchFilterInConfigItemLookUp and enter randome values in input box (like- "abc", "xyz", true). i should be able to get all these above entered values in JSON form and print them on console.

Comment: @user1814044 I have updated my answer. I am not able to do it using angular way. If you have an answer then post it here.

Comment: @Che- i tried this JS way only. not able to find out any other option working.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you need to get values from the dynamic input elements. For that, you need to set ng-model to the input elements, not to the div.

The below updated part would help.

```
<div ng-init="pageObjectName.pageObjParam={}" ng-repeat="(key , value) in pageObjectName.pageObjMethod">
    <input ng-model='pageObjectName.pageObjParam[key]' value='' placeholder="{{key}} - {{value}}"></input>
</div>
```

Now you can get those values from $scope.pageObjectName.pageObjParam.

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gLAPD2pO4vfQqpxFIGp8?p=preview)

EDIT

I hope the above part helped to get value from dynamic input fields. Now I suggest you to update the code block like below to get the selected values from dropdown (ie, use one hidden input field for each select) and you will get what you want.

```
 <select id="pageObj" ng-model="pageObjectName.pageObj" ng-options="key for (key,value) in pageData" ng-change="pageObjectName.pageObjParam.pageObj=pageObjectName.pageObj">
    <option value=''>Select Page Object</option>
    </select>
 <input ng-model='pageObjectName.pageObjParam.pageObj' hidden/>
```

[You can have a look at the same plunker now](http://plnkr.co/edit/gLAPD2pO4vfQqpxFIGp8?p=preview)

Comment: so i wont be able to get the dropdown selected values is it? only input values can be get?

Comment: You already got the dropdown value from $scope.pageObjectName.pageObj, right? This one is for getting values from dynamic input elements in addition. You can just merge them by $scope.pageObjectName.pageObj.pageObjParam = $scope.pageObjectName.pageObjParam

Comment: no i did not. if i console this     var data =  $scope.pageObjectName.pageObj;
       console.log("json is", data); it does not give me correct selected dropdown values. instead it gives me second dropdown all options.

Comment: @Pitchai- This still did not work for me. I am still getting the whole list of options which are available in json, not the selected one. So i tried the above mentioned answer by using id's and using the simple JS way.